# Correct Github Application URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, github, ruby-on-rails-4

What are the correct URLs to register in an application in Github? I have a rails application that I am trying to connect to github through omniauth/devise. The problem is that each time I tried to authenticate through devise I get this URL

```
> http://127.0.0.1:4000/auth/github/callback?error=redirect_uri_mismatch...
```

in my browser and NULL feedback from GitHub. (that means the env['omniauth.auth'] is null).

This is my Github URLs. What is wrong here?

```
Application Name:
Foo

URL:
http://127.0.0.1:4000/users/auth/github

Callback URL:
http://127.0.0.1:4000/auth/github/callback
```

Answer (score 3):

Devise omniauth expects other callback URL.

Try:

```
URL:
http://127.0.0.1:4000

Callback URL:
http://127.0.0.1:4000/users/auth/github/callback
```